# how to open a GUI from a menu Bar in tkinter python

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am a newbie to tkinter. I am just trying to develop a desktop application in tkinter. I have created three files, one for user, second for Item and third for Company. New I want to create a parent form like MDIParent in dotnet framework. I want to link all my files with menus in parent form. I used Menu class to create menu and sub-menus. Code is given below:

```
from tkinter import*
import pyodbc 
from tkinter import messagebox , Menu  
class Wall:
        def __init__(self, root):
                self.root = root
                self.root.title("Bakery Management System")
                self.root.resizable(False,False)
                self.root.geometry("1360x680+0+0")
# Creating Menu bar for Applicaiton

                Frame_login = Frame(self.root, bg='white',borderwidth = 3, relief = "sunken")
                Frame_login.place(x=10,y=5, height =100 , width =620)
                login_Button = Button(Frame_login,text = "Login",command=self.user_definition,cursor="hand2", font=("Times New Roman" , 12)).place(x=2,y=10, height =40 , width =125)
        

                menubar = Menu(root)  
                file = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
                file.add_command(label="Exit", command=root.quit)  
        
                menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file)  
                definition = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
                definition.add_command(label="User Definition", command=self.user_definition) 
                definition.add_separator()
                definition.add_command(label="Company Definition", command=self.company_definition)  
                definition.add_separator()
                definition.add_command(label="Item Definition ", command=self.item_definition)  
                menubar.add_cascade(label="System Definition", menu=definition)  
        
                purchase = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
                purchase.add_command(label="Item Purchase ")  
                menubar.add_cascade(label="Purchases", menu=purchase)  
        
                sales = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)  
                sales.add_command(label="Item Sales")  
                menubar.add_cascade(label="Sales", menu=sales)  
                root.config(menu=menubar) 
        def user_definition(self):
                import user.py
                
        def company_definition(self):
                import items.py

        def item_definition(self):
                import itemCompany.py
                
                

       
root = Tk()
obj = Wall(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Now the issue: When i click on a sub-menu the intended form is opened thats fine. when I close the file and click again on file the file is not opening. i clicked again and again but the file is not operning.

Please suggest how to handle it...

Comment: `import user.py`, for example, will import and execute `user.py` once.  The file will not be imported and executed when it is called second time.  Put the main code block of `user.py` in a function and use `from user import some_function` and then execute the function `some_function()`.

Comment: Thank you soo much it really worked for me. stay Blessed.....